# Selecting Features from a Feature Class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Some ARC tools seem to only to accept feature classes ( e.g.Generate Near Table) rather than layers as data input. If you had a featureclass with more than one feature how do you select the the feature you require if you cannot used the layer "definition query?? Or have Imissed something?

Comment: What version of ArcMap? The latest version of [Generate Near Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm) accepts Feature Layers.

Answer (score 1):

I am confused by your statement that Generate Near Table cannot accept a feature layer as input because its [usage](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm#ESRI_USAGES_9F860D54AD4C42478C5C32C545212B3A) indicates that in_features are "The input features that can be point, polyline, polygon, or multipoint type." of data type "Feature Layer".

However, to answer your actual question, the tool you could use is [Select](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm):

> Extracts features from an input feature class or input feature layer,
>   typically using a select or Structured Query Language (SQL) expression
>   and stores them in an output feature class.

Comment: I have generated two feature classes in the gdb, the input and near  feature class for the "Near" tool so I could have multiple features in each class and select using the layer "definition query". When using layers with "Near" the tool produced an empty table - error  "input feature class empty".  When I presented single feature feature classes to near "Near" it functioned correctly. The suggestion to use Select and an intermediate  feature table implies my direct approach will not work, why is that? I seem to be missing a principle here. I have  Arc 10.3.